# How can I install an electrical plug without a stud nearby?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box

I need to place an electrical outlet where there is no stud. Where can I find outlets to do this?

Comment: Is/will there be drywall? Or will the walls remain open? What is your level of experience with electrical building wiring?

Answer (score 4):

If you're installing it in a drywall wall, you'd use what's known as an **old work** box.

[image: old work box]

They can be found on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001DPNQPW)

Comment: ....or ANY home center, hardware store, etc. This is an extremely common item.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I assumed if the OP didn't know where to get them, they didn't have access to a hardware store.  Maybe it's a bad assumption.

Comment: My point was more surprise that he is doing electrical work and has never heard of nor seen an old-work box. This is one of the most common items in the trade, and is available everywhere.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey What's common to a magician, is magic to others.

Comment: +1 But a short explanation of how it holds in drywall would be useful to both the OP and subsequent readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dry lining wall back box from any DIY store.

[image]

[Typical video of fitting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5tdMUE28Zo)
[Typical web-search result](http://www.screwfix.com/p/appleby-1-gang-35mm-dry-lining-box/44827)

Of course, the answer may vary a bit depending on whether you live in

- Sheffield, Alabama
- Sheffield, Tasmania
- Sheffield, Yorkshire

or not in Sheffield at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the wall is currently open, or will be opened, you can also add framing between the studs and use a new-work, nail to framing, type of box. The correct solution depends on the details of your situation.